Pear leaves developeing black stains
A ten year old pear tree has started developing black(not dark brown) and growing regions on it's leaves. Here is a leaf underside:

Sometimes numerous black spots develop but only one grows into a stain:

The leaves eventually die:

The tree still fruits:

Is this dangerous? How to treat it?
This is in a temperate region that however develops 40°C in July. Watering is mostly natural with a couple of times an year manual. The tree has not been treated with anything ever.

That looks like Fabraea leaf spot, a blight. You should verify, and then spray with the appropriate fungicide treatment.
It isn't immediately dangerous, but left unchecked can ruin fruit and eventually kill the tree.

Thanks a metric ton!!! Would that be visible under a microscope - say x100 - or would it instead require a laboratory and some chemicals turning the tissue into another color?

Interesting question. I think it would be hard to identify with just a 100x microscope. Apparently the normal way to do it is to cut the leaf, place in dye and see how the cut oozes. But if you have a 100x scope handy, you could always try it and see if you can spot the spores.

Ehehe - not advancing the Q or the A in any way but I simply can't not share: I do have the scope but I don't have the leaves.

Nah, forget about the "less then a week": SE culture requires a problem to be resolved before marking an answer as accepted. That's at least an year from now. But what I can assure You is I won't forget about a question that is important to me.

Don't worry about it for my benefit, i'm not super concerned about points here
